# how to make some changes in package after adding package to pubspec.yaml in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I added a package  [power file view](https://pub.dev/packages/power_file_view) to view different files now I want to do some changes inside this package like the language by default is Chinese I want to convert it to English. someone, please.

Comment: I believe they use webview to render files. You can not change the default language.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive they use webview to render files. You cannot change the default language.

According to package description:

> Android uses Tencent TBS service, supports preview of doc, docx, ppt,
> pptx, xls, xlsx, pdf, txt, epub files

> ios uses WKWebView, all supported by WKWebView can be previewed

You can use [`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to render supported files as well.

```
var file_link ='https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf';

WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$file_link',
);
```

for older version of `webview_flutter`

for `webview_flutter: 4.0.0` above

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class DocsView extends StatelessWidget {
  DocsView({super.key, required this.url});
  final String url;
  final controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.loadRequest(
        Uri.parse(('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=$url')));
    return WebViewWidget(
      controller: controller,
    );
  }
}
```

> use it like :

```
DocsView(url:'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf');
```

Comment: now how to solve this want to convert language to english for my android application

Comment: Add [`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package as a dependency.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a demo.

Comment: is this for web i need for android

Comment: Its for both android and ios

Comment: wht if i am getting files from internal storage

Comment: Why would you open local files inside your app?

Comment: i am getting different files list inside my flutter app like pdf,pptx and then view these files but im unabele to view .rtf files